# 'Could not find public_suffix-3.0.2 in any of the sources' when run ruby in Lambda

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda

I have a ruby script that needs to run on Lambda,  I created a function, with all the files in a folder
When I test it, got an error:

```
"errorMessage": "Could not find public_suffix-3.0.2 in any of the sources"
```

I already add this library in `Gemfile.lock`, so I am confused why this is happening and how do I fix it?
This is how I defined it in `Gemfile.lock`:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    .......
```

Comment: try deleting `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again see if you run to any issues then. Before you upload to Lambda

Comment: I see the versions don't match `public_suffix (>= 2.0.2)`  != `public_suffix-3.0.2`

Answer (score 1):

It seems as that your `public_suffix` versions don't match.

Add to your Gemfile.

`gem 'public_suffix', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.2'`

Run `bundle install`

Make sure that the version is upgraded in your `Gemfile.lock` and add folder to Lambda.